# changing limits on shared axes in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Hi I am using `subplots` to create an 2x2 array of plots with shared axes. I want to share the x-axis per column and the y-axis per row

```
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = subplots(2,2, sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
```

Now I expect to be able to modify separately the limits on for instance the x-axis of the first column (`ax1` and `ax3`) and the ones of the second column (so `ax2` and `ax4`)
But when I do

```
ax1.set_xlim(3,5)
ax2.set_xlim(4,10)
```

I end up with all x-limits set to (4,10) ?? Even though in the original constructor call I specifically set `sharex = 'col'` and  `sharey = 'row'`

What am I missing ? Same of course for the y-axis for which I want to modify the limits separately per row

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? It works fine for me on 1.3.1. 
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/RutgerK/10472582

Comment: Hmmmm I am using 1.1.1rc...

Comment: OK apparently it was a version bug... after installing 1.3.1 (with all the related problems see for instance freetype and libpng which pip doesnt install automatically) it is OK.

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem Please post your comment as an answer and edit your post title to removed the 'solved' comment.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer by Rutger Kassies and OP.*

It's a bug in matplotlib 1.1.1rc.
It's working in matplotlib 1.3.1, as demonstrated by http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/RutgerK/10472582